# Ruby: how are instance variables shared between two separate classes?

Tags: ruby

To preface, I am a raw Ruby novice, and fairly new to coding as well, so please forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to figure out a hypothetical exercise involving two classes, and passing variables between an instance of one class to the other. I've been searching for answers, but can't seem to find anything that applies directly to this kind of case.

```
class Person
 def initialize(name, age)
     @name = name
     @age = age
     puts "Hi #{@name}, you are #{@age}."
 end
end

class Town
 def initialize(town_name)
     @town_name = town_name
     puts "Welcome to #{@town_name}!"
 end
 def buy_house(person)
     puts "#{@name}, at age #{@age}, you bought a house in #{@town_name}!"
 end
end
```

When I instantiate Person and Town, I can see the instance variables being set:

```
me = Person.new("Daniel", 38)
townville = Town.new("Townville")
```

My real question is: how do I pass the variables set for the instance of "me" into any methods defined in Town using something like the line below?

```
townville.buy_house(me)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `puts "#{@name}..."` inside an instance of `Town` to refer to a `Person`'s `@name` instance variable. `@variable` always refers to a variable belonging to the current object. If you want to access `Person`'s instance variables, you need to make accessors for them.

You can do so by explicitly defining methods on `Person` which operate on the instance variables, or using `attr_reader`/`attr_writer`/`attr_accessor` which do so for you:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :age

  # the above line is equivalent to defining two methods:
  # def name; @name; end
  # def age; @age; end

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    puts "Hi #{@name}, you are #{@age}."
  end
end

# class Town ...

  def buy_house(person)
    puts "#{person.name}, at age #{person.age}, you bought a house in #{@town_name}!"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "inject" all the instance variables of one object into another, that is absolutely possible. Whether this is useful or not is up to you to decide:

```
class Object
  def inject_instance_variables(other)
    other.instance_variables.each do |var|
      self.instance_variable_set(var, other.instance_variable_get(var))
    end
  end
end
```